# Вывести php переменную в html которая в echo

Tags: php, html

```
<header class='panel-title'>
 <div class='text-center'>
 <strong>$result[0]->first_name $result[0]->last_name</strong>
 </div>
 </header>
```

Этот html код находиться в echo, как тут правильно вывеести переменную которая $result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php

echo "<header class='panel-title'>
     <div class='text-center'>
     <strong>".$result[0]->first_name ." ". $result[0]->last_name."</strong>
     </div>
     </header>"

?>
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '}' in D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 93`

Comment: поправил свой ответ

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

ну или еще как более читабельный вариант, чтоб потом не запутаться в `."` и им подобным конструкциям:

```
<?php
    echo "<header class='panel-title'>
    <div class='text-center'>
        <strong>{$result[0]->first_name} {$result[0]->last_name}</strong>
    </div>
    </header>";

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<header class='panel-title'>
    <div class='text-center'>
        <strong><?php echo $result[0]->first_name ." ". $result[0]->last_name; ?></strong>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: этот код уже в echo именно html. а при вводе вашего кода `syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in `

Comment: @Михаил, я так понял в полях скорее всего есть такие ковычки ', тогда в место .' '., нужно ." ".